# Set nowplayingInfo for showing metadata not work on airplay Apple TV

Tags: metadata, avplayer, airplay, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I am sending metadata from an audio app via the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter : title, artist, artwork....

On iPhone devices, all this information is correctly displayed in the control center of the device (as well as in Carplay which uses also these metadata or in the Apple Watch).

But on Apple TV via airplay (MPVolumView), I just see a black screen with a progress bar.

I registered via KVO on the AVPlayerItem timedMetadata, but as soon as I play on AppleTV I do not receive any notification anymore as an observer.

Do someone have the same problem?

Thank you a lot for any responses.

Answer (score 2):

Set the bool allowsexternalplayback to false

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if I set this property to false else I will not be able to make Airplay working ?

Comment: This is strange but when i set this flag to false then it worked for me very fine.

Comment: This is super weird, this works and solves the issue, but the AirPlay button is removed from the player, you have to go into it via the notification centre's now playing to cast it. Possibly able to add my own airplay button, but this is dumb